# django media_root not working

Tags: django, django-settings, django-staticfiles, django-media

I'm using django 1.6

in my settings I have this, which works fine,

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),

)
```

but the moment I add: `MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/'),

I get a error while rendering a template:

```
'tuple' does not support the buffer interface
```

*problem code:* `<link href=" {% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %} " rel="stylesheet">`

Is there some kind of conflict between these 2 settings? all I'm trying to do is serve user uploaded files, should I just change the *upload_to* setting to the static directory?

has anyone experienced this before or know what might be the problem

any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just fixed your string in **settings.py**

### Your

> MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/'),

### Fixed

> MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

*Without ,*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing the `os` library, you should import `os.path`, as done followingly:

```
import os.path
```